# formula for pricing bond-futures

Tags: pricing, bond-futures

Is anybody able to help me understanding why does $P_t(S)$ appear in the  solution to the following problem; deriving the price of bond forward contracts?
Thank you
Given:

- $r_t$, the instantaneous rate process
- $P_t(T)$, the price of a zero-coupon bond at $t$ and expiring at $T$
- $F_t(S,T)$, the price at $t$ of a forward expiring at $S\leq T$
- $B_S(T)$, the price at $S$ of a coupon-bearing bond expiring at $T>t$

The payoff for going long the forward is $B_S(T)-F_t(S,T)$, and the position is costless at inception such that, in the absence of arbitrage, the forward satisfies
$F_t(S,T)=\frac{1}{P_t(S)}\mathbb{E}_t\left(e^{-\int_t^Sr_\tau d\tau} B_S(T)\right)$
where $\mathbb{E}_t$ denotes the expectation

Comment: What is $F_t(S,T)$? You say is the forward expiring... you mean the forward rate? or is $F_t(S,T)$ the forward price of the coupon-bearing bond $B_S(T)$?

Comment: $F_t(S, T)$ is the price at $t$ of the forward (or futures) contract

Comment: What contract? The underlying asset is the coupon-bearing bond, right?

Comment: Yes, the contract $F_t(S, T)$ is a forward contract in which the underlying asset $B_S(T)$ is a coupon-bearing bond.

Comment: Is the conditional expectation taken under the risk-neutral measure or under the forward measure? When is the inception, $t=0$ or just $t$?

Comment: The conditional expectation is taken under the risk-neutral measure. My initial guess was the inception is defined at $t$ but I am not longer certain of that now

Comment: Does the expression for $F_t(S,T)$ later simplify in your notes/book? By definition $P(t,S)=\mathbb{E}_t\left(e^{-\int_t^Sr_\tau d\tau} \right)$ so you end up with    $F_t(S,T)={E}_t\left( B_S(T)\right).$

Comment: No, the final expression is $F_t(S, T)=\frac{B_t(T)}{P_t(S)}$
FYI, the source is [link](https://antoniomele.org/wp-content/uploads/handbook_fixed_income.pdf) section 20.3.1.2

Comment: It's equivalent, $F_t(S,T) = E_t(B_S(T))=1/P(t,S)E_t(P(t,S)B_S(T))=1/P(t,S)B_t(T)).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the forward contract matures at time $S$ and $0 \leq t < S < T.$ Let $F_t(S,T)$ be the price that makes the forward contract be worth zero at time $t$. Then by the risk-neutral valuation formula we obtain
$$0= \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left[(B_S(T) - F_t(S,T))e^{-\int_t^S r(u)du} | \mathcal F_t \right].$$
Since $ F_t(S,T))e^{-\int_t^S r(u)du}$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable,
$$F_t(S,T)=e^{\int_t^S r(u)du} \mathbb E^{\mathbb Q} \left[B_S(T)e^{-\int_t^S r(u)du} | \mathcal F_t \right].$$ Under the risk-neutral probability measure $\mathbb Q$ the discounted bearing-bond is a martingale, so
$$F_t(S,T)=e^{\int_t^S r(u)du} B_t(T)=\frac{1}{P_t(S)}B_t(T).$$

Comment: I guess there's a small typo in the first equation. It should $F_t(S,T)$ instead of $F_S(S,T)$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo.